# build.gradle.kts build openAPI classes from different interfaces

Tags: kotlin, gradle, openapi, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I use **build.gradle.kts** build file to create the client stub from an **openApi** description yaml file.

This work well for only **one** interface (interface1.yaml)

To create the stub I use :
gradlew openApiGenerate

Snippend form my build.gradle.kts file :

```java
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set("kotlin")
 
    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/sharedSDK/openApi/interface1.yaml")
 
    outputDir.set("$rootDir/sharedSDK/")
    configOptions.set(mapOf( "dateLibrary" to "java8" ))

    modelPackage.set("package.inteface1.model")
  
    library.set("multiplatform") 
    
    generateModelTests.set(false)
    generateApiTests.set(false)
    generateModelDocumentation.set(false)
    generateApiDocumentation.set(false)
    modelNamePrefix.set("V2")  

    globalProperties.set(
        mapOf(
            //"apis" to "false",
            //"models" to "true"
            "models" to "" // generate only model stuff
        ))
}
```

Now I need to generate the sub classes for a **second** interface form a different yaml description (interface2.yaml)

How to do this ?

2 openApiGenerate { ... } task in one file didn't work

Is there a way to pass my openApiGenerate { ... } definition to an customer task

Thanks
Stephan

Comment: Are both `interface1` and `interface1` valid openapi specifications that you are trying to combine into one specification?  Or are you just trying to run the generator with two different specifications?  It sounds like the 2nd one, but I want to be sure before I answer.

Comment: Interface1 and Interface2 are valid openapi specifications from different services which have a different release cycles.
I like to run the generator with two different specifications.

Answer (score 2):

## Define your tasks by type

Gradle allows you to define multiple tasks of the same type.  For kotlin, you can do this as follow:

```kotlin
tasks.register<GenerateTask>("GenerateInterface1"){
    generatorName.set("kotlin")
 
    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/sharedSDK/openApi/interface1.yaml")
 
    outputDir.set("$rootDir/sharedSDK/")
    configOptions.set(mapOf( "dateLibrary" to "java8" ))

    modelPackage.set("package.inteface1.model")
  
    library.set("multiplatform") 
    
    generateModelTests.set(false)
    generateApiTests.set(false)
    generateModelDocumentation.set(false)
    generateApiDocumentation.set(false)
    modelNamePrefix.set("V2")  

    globalProperties.set(
        mapOf(
            //"apis" to "false",
            //"models" to "true"
            "models" to "" // generate only model stuff
        ))
}
```

## Shared Config

If you are using a lot of the same config options, you can move them to their own file.  This has the added benefit of making your tasks much more concise, but you will still need to define a few properties specific to each task.

```kotlin
tasks.register<GenerateTask>("GenerateInterface1"){
    generatorName.set("kotlin")
    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/sharedSDK/openApi/interface1.yaml")
    outputDir.set("$rootDir/sharedSDK/")
    configFile.set("$rootDir/sharedSDK/generatorConfig.yml")
    modelPackage.set("package.interface1.model")
}

tasks.register<GenerateTask>("GenerateInterface2"){
    generatorName.set("kotlin")
    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/sharedSDK/openApi/interface2.yaml")
    outputDir.set("$rootDir/sharedSDK/")
    configFile.set("$rootDir/sharedSDK/generatorConfig.yml")
    modelPackage.set("package.interface2.model")
}
```

Now you can move all your configuration settings to your yaml file to be shared by both generators.

Comment: Hi tbatch, 
This is exact the solution I am looking for.
Thanks you saved my day.

Comment: I'm glad this helped.  If this answered your question, please consider excepting it as an answer.